# PHP - Filtering

Tags: php, post

I am trying to assign a value to a variable through a form created in html

Form returns place holder website_features and based on the value being good or bad, i want it to return numeric 4 or 2 
Tried the below code with error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce2\feedback.php
Any help is appreciated

```
$Website_score= if ($_POST['website_features']='GOOD')
                                      {echo '4'}
                                      else {echo '2'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign an `if` operation to a variable.

Depending on your requirements (it's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do), you *could* try…

```
$Website_score = 0;

if ($_POST['website_features'] == 'GOOD') {
    $Website_score = 4;
} else {
    $Website_score =  2;
};

echo $Website_score;
```

Comment: Hi . Thank you for the reply. I am trying to create a calculated field based on feedback. If user feedback is good , then 4 is assigned as score which I’m logging into phpmyadmin. Your code is stopping at the else statement .

Comment: @jagann Apologies - there was a missing semi-colon. (Fixed now.) To be honest I’d recommend trying to find some PHP tutorials to follow before tackling a problem like this - having a have a good grasp of the basics will save you a lot of time.